# How to set up a wireless AP with a linux box and SOCKS proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, wifi, socks

I've got:

(1) Linux box (Arch linux to be precise, but that doesn't really matter)

(2) Ethernet connection on it (say, *eth0*)

(3) Socks proxy on a remote site (say, *remote* :*port*), which can be accessed through (2)

(4) Wireless card on local linux box (say, *eth1*)

So, the task is: create a wireless access point using (4) on local site (1) in such a way that all connections from it will go through proxy (3). E.g., when one simply connects to that AP (well, there should be DHCP or something for that) and goes to serverfault.com, all the traffic goes through that SOCKS proxy.

I'm just asking for the digging direction and some references, not step-by-step tutorial.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Though it's possible to do this all with Linux, I'd ditch that idea and go with [PFsense](http://pfsense.org/) instead. It's a FreeBSD-based routing/firewall distro. I believe it should do everything you need with its out-of-the-box configuration, with only the addition of the Squid package to set up a SOCKS proxy (or transparent, if desired). I've been using PFsense for years, and it's a very solid product, with a great community surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a transparent socks proxy, using
[redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/)
or 
[TranSocks](http://transocks.sourceforge.net/)
or something similar.